# Need help to identify this timer

Tags: timer, delay, automatic-circuit-breaker

This device is installed in our electrical panel which act as a timer to control the on/off operation for our LED billboard outside my office. I searched around the device for the brand and model it did not state anything or probably written in chinese character which I am not familiar. The previous electrical engineer already left without leaving his technician any clue on how to operate this device.

Now I need to reprogram it to switch on the billboard at a different time. it has one serial cable that can be connected to a laptop and the technician told me the previous engineer used to plug it to his laptop and run a program called "MK Power" to program the timer. I guess that software came with the device since the tech described a window based program with specifics fields to set time and delay.

Anybody recognize the device and know where I could find the software for it?
[image]

Comment: Probably not going to get much help here, as that is off topic.. Might try reddit r/plc.  In any event, that is some brick PLC, from someone.  Would need a manufacturer and model number to even make a guess.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion.. will try..

Comment: That is **not** merely a timer.   That is an industrial control unit.  A "programmable logic controller" (PLC.)  It can do simple timing things, but also much more complicated things.  Changing the time may be more complicated than you expect.

Comment: Post a shake-free, in focus, decent resolution photo of the maker's label.

Comment: @Transistor, lens flare and a decent bokeh would also be nice. :)

Comment: @JRE yes I have to agree.. I suspect what the technician described as software might be a ladder project file for that specific device. its kinda fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the make and model. But i have a link for the manual for MASTER-K PLC programmer:

http://foster.pl/pdf/plc/manuals/MK120S_Users_Manual.pdf

I hope it is useful for you!

Comment: Thanks @Rajat. I have looked into it. The KGL_WIN might be it but unless i could find the previous project file, i think its a dead end.

Comment: Okay! all the best :)